# looking for a more pythonic way to access the database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a bunch of python methods that follow this pattern:

```
def delete_session(guid):
    conn = get_conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("delete from sessions where guid=%s", guid)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Is there a more pythonic way to execute raw sql. The 2 lines at the beginning and end of every method are starting to bother me.

I'm not looking for an orm, I want to stick with raw sql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a context manager and use the with statement.  For example, see [this blog post (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329070622/http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/03/get-with-the-program-as-contextmanager-completely-different/)

Also the python documentation has a sample that pretty much matches your needs.  See section 8.1 on this page, in particular the snippet that begins:

```
db_connection = DatabaseConnection()
with db_connection as cursor:
    cursor.execute('insert into ...')
    cursor.execute('delete from ...')
    # ... more operations ...
```

- https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html

Answer (score 3):

Careful about that `execute`, the second argument needs to be [guid] (a list with just one item).  As for your question, I normally just use a class encapsulating connection and cursor, but it looks like you may prefer to use an *execution context* object whose `__enter__` method gives you a cursor while `__leave__` commits or rollbacks depending on whether the termination was normal or by exception; this would make your code

```
def delete_session():
    with get_cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(etc etc)
```

If you like this style, let us know and I'll show you how to write `get_cursor`. Others will no doubt propose a decorator instead, so you'd write:

```
@withcursor
def delete_session(cur):
    cur.execute(etc etc)
```

but I think this makes commit/rollback, among other issues, a bit murkier. Still, if *this* is your preference, again let us know and I can show you how to write that form, too.

Comment: It works fine with the guid alone. Is there an issue I'm unaware of?

Comment: I think I like the context manager approach. The link given by ars describes it well enough, but thanks for the offer.

Comment: @Ben, the 2nd argument to cursor.execute must be a sequence of values (typically a tuple) if you're using positional parameter substitution (like your %s or in other DB API modules ? or :1) or a mapping (typically a dict) if you use named parameter substitution (like :guid in certain DB API modules) -- not sure what DB API module you're using, but it's being pretty weird in letting you get away with other forms such as one isolated, non-sequence, non-mapping 2nd argument.

Answer (score 3):

"I have a bunch of python methods that follow this pattern:"

This is confusing.

Either you have a bunch of functions, or you have a bunch of methods of a class.

**Bunch of Functions**.

Do this instead.

```
class SQLFunction( object ):
    def __init__( self, connection ):
        self.connection = connection
    def __call__( self, args=None ):
        self.cursor= self.connection.cursor()
        self.run( args )
        self.cursor.commit()
        self.cursor.close()

class DeleteSession( SQLFunction ):
    def run( self, args ):
        self.cursor.execute( "statement" )

delete_session = DeleteSession( connection )
```

Your function declarations are two lines longer, but essentially the same.
You can do `func1( args )` because it's a callable object.  The rest of
your program should remain unchanged.

**Bunch of Methods in One Class**.

```
class SomeClass( object ):
    def __init__( self, connection ):
        self.connection= connection
    def sql_execute( self, statement, args= None )
        self.cursor= self.connection.cursor() 
        self.cursor.execute( statement, args if args is not None else [] )
        self.connection.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
    def delete_session( self ):
        self.sql_execute( "statement" )
```

All your methods can look like delete_session and make use of a common `sql_execute` method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be more pythonic, just more structured:

```
def execSql(statement):
    conn = get_conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(statement)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def delete_session(guid):
    execSql("delete from sessions where guid=%s"%(guid))
```

Comment: Some of the methods I write will need to interact with the results. Seems like it would be awkward with this method. Can you call the fetch methods after the connection is closed?

Comment: No, this is useful only for one-shot operations.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator?

```
class SqlExec:
   def __init__ (self, f):
      self.f = f
   def __call__ (self, *args):
      conn = get_conn() 
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute(self.f (*args))
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()

@SqlExec
def delete_session(guid):
      return "delete from sessions where guid=%s" % guid
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-shortcut-methods), if you were using SQLite3, you wouldn't even *need* a `Cursor` which, as the docs say, is "often superfluous".

Instead you can use the shortcut methods `execute` `executemany` and `executescript` directly on the connection object:

```
import sqlite3

persons = [
    ("Hugo", "Boss"),
    ("Calvin", "Klein")
    ]

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

# Create the table
con.execute("create table person(firstname, lastname)")

# Fill the table
con.executemany("insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", persons)

# Print the table contents
for row in con.execute("select firstname, lastname from person"):
    print row

print "I just deleted", con.execute("delete from person").rowcount, "rows"
```