# Context manager for Python's MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, with-statement, contextmanager

I am used to (spoiled by?) python's [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) interface to deal with SQL databases.  One nice feature in python's SQLite's API  the "context manager," i.e., python's `with` statement.  I usually execute queries in the following way:

```
import as sqlite

with sqlite.connect(db_filename) as conn:
    query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO shapes VALUES (?,?);"
    results = conn.execute(query, ("ID1","triangle"))
```

With the code above, if my query modifies the database and I forget to run `conn.commit()`,the context manager runs it for me automatically upon exiting the `with` statement. It also handles exceptions nicely: if an exception occurs before I commit anything, then the database is rolled back.

I am now using the `MySQLdb` interface, which doesn't seem to support a similar context manager out of the box.  How do I create my own?  There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107297/looking-for-a-more-pythonic-way-to-access-the-database), but it doesn't offer a complete solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840557/190597), MySQLdb connections were context managers.
As of [this commit on 2018-12-04](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/commit/c64915b1e5c705f4fb10e86db5dcfed0b58552cc), however, MySQLdb connections are no longer context managers,
and users must explicitly call conn.commit() or conn.rollback(), or write their own context manager, such as the one below.

---

You could use something like this:

```
import config
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as mc
import _mysql_exceptions
import contextlib
DictCursor = mc.DictCursor
SSCursor = mc.SSCursor
SSDictCursor = mc.SSDictCursor
Cursor = mc.Cursor

@contextlib.contextmanager
def connection(cursorclass=Cursor,
               host=config.HOST, user=config.USER,
               passwd=config.PASS, dbname=config.MYDB,
               driver=MySQLdb):
    connection = driver.connect(
            host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=dbname,
            cursorclass=cursorclass)
    try:
        yield connection
    except Exception:
        connection.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def cursor(cursorclass=Cursor, host=config.HOST, user=config.USER,
           passwd=config.PASS, dbname=config.MYDB):
    with connection(cursorclass, host, user, passwd, dbname) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
            yield cursor
        finally:
            cursor.close()


with cursor(SSDictCursor) as cur:
    print(cur)
    connection = cur.connection
    print(connection)
    sql = 'select * from table'
    cur.execute(sql)
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
```

To use it you would place `config.py` in your PYTHONPATH and define the HOST, USER, PASS, MYDB variables there.

Comment: Excellent solution!  Not only did you give the answer for MySQLdb, it can also be used with other drivers.  Also, oursql looks promising.  Thanks.

Comment: @unutbu shouldn't the connectio be initialized in the __enter__ function? I think it's much safer. Here's an example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/

Comment: @callmeGuy: The `__exit__` function assumes that `self.connection` exists. If you instantiate the connection in the `__enter__` function and it raises an exception, then the `__exit__` function will raise a second exception since there would be no `connection` to call `rollback` or `commit` on. So no, it would not be safer.

Comment: @callmeGuy: Further corroboration can be found in the [github source code](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/commit/c64915b1e5c705f4fb10e86db5dcfed0b58552cc). You can see the developers (prior to the change) did not initialize the connection in `__enter__`. See also this [doc example](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#example).

Comment: @callmeGuy: Your question did prompt me to rewrite the code, however.  Connections and cursors are not the same things so I've separated the two so each is its own context manager. I also switched to using the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator instead of defining `__enter__` and `__exit__` explicitly since it makes the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: @unutbu I wish you kept you code as a class, for me at least it's more useful. Anyways, interesting points you've raised

Answer (score 20):

Think things have changed since this question was originally asked. Somewhat confusingly (from my point of view at least), for recent versions of `MySQLdb`, if you use a connection in a context you get a cursor (as per the `oursql` example), not something that closes automatically (as you would if you opened a file for instance).

Here's what I do:

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(getConnection()) as conn: #ensure that the connection is closed
    with conn as cursor:               #cursor will now auto-commit
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tablename')
```

Comment: Auto commit? As in, auto commit mode, so you have no transaction?