# Can I use with statement with MySQLdb.Connection object?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I wonder if I can use the context manager `with` with the `Connection` object, and write code like this:

```
with MySQLdb.connect(...) as conn:
    do_something()
```

Will the `conn` object be closed automatically after the block like with a `file` object ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQLdb does not support the context manager protocol. [Roll your own, or use oursql instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067690/context-manager-for-pythons-mysqldb)

Comment: Did you ask the asker to pay a bounty two write his code for him in the other question, or did I misinterpret it?

Comment: @TankorSmash: Not a bounty specifically; I also accept PayPal transfers and Amazon Canada gift certificates.

Comment: Well, I guess everybody needs to make a living somehow.

Comment: This answer is obsolete; MySQLdb has had this feature for some time. See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22618781/2359271).