# Python MySQLdb "with" syntax and DictCursor

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to use a [DictCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html) with a `with` block.  I would think that by using:

```
with MySQLdb.connect(...) as c:
```

`c` would be a connection object, because that's what connect() returns.  But alas, it is not!  All of a sudden, `c` is a cursor!  While this is usually convenient, I really like using a `DictCursor` - is this not designed that way at all?  Enclosing the DictCursor as the "scoped object" causes an error (`__exit__` wasn't defined)

Comment: It appears the `with` statement is not supported: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11751859/707650).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of the Connection in MySQLdb here [line 254 of connections.py](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py#L254), Connection.cursor() will return an instance of Connection.cursorclass:

```
def cursor(self, cursorclass=None):
    """
    Create a cursor on which queries may be performed. The
    optional cursorclass parameter is used to create the
    Cursor. By default, self.cursorclass=cursors.Cursor is
    used.
    """
    return (cursorclass or self.cursorclass)(self)
```

so, I guess if you initialize the connection with the argument "cursorclass", and set it to MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, like:

```
dbconn = MySQLdb.connect(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

when it comes

```
def __enter__(self):
    if self.get_autocommit():
        self.query("BEGIN")
    return self.cursor()
```

it will return a dict cursor.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is a cursor because that's what is returned from the `__enter__` method of the context manager.
If you browse Mysqldb's source code, you'll be able to see in [`line 245 of connections.py`](https://github.com/jehiah/mysql-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py#L245):

```
def __enter__(self): return self.cursor()
```

As for `DictCursor`, it does not support context management.

Comment: I'm a little confused - doesn't `with MySQLdb.connect(...) as c:` work?  Or have I missed something?  At least it doesn't raise an exception!

Comment: yeah, it works but as i said it is designed to return a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

My fix for raw sql with sqlalchemy

```
if self.engine.url.drivername == 'mysql+pymysql':
    from pymysql.cursors import SSDictCursor
    connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor=SSDictCursor)
elif self.engine.url.drivername == 'mysql+mysqldb':
    import MySQLdb.cursors
    connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
else:
    connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

or use when create connection

```
connect_args=dict(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```