# how to implement a lockfile-like mechanism between celery workers?

Tags: mysql, locking, celery, mysql-python, django-celery

I have a distributed computation framework which uses Celery + RABBITMQ + supervisor. The tasks of my worker involve reading from a database, computing some values and updating the database after the process is done. However, when I try and run multiple workers in a distributed fashion, I keep hitting the error :-

(2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Can anyone suggest me a way to setup a mutex or lockfile-like mechanism, so that the workers can access the database concurrently.

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks,
Amit

Edit :-

```
con = mdb.connect(parameters...)

def reset_table(table_name,con):
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("UPDATE " + table_name + " SET active_status = 0 where last_access <     (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)")
        con.commit()
```

StackTrace :-

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 238, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 416, in    __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/elasticsearch/celery_test/tasks.py", line 183, in download_data
    auth = get_auth(con)
  File "/home/elasticsearch/celery_test/tasks.py", line 94, in get_auth
    reset_table("auths",con)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 249, in __exit__
    self.rollback()
ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't hurry to apply a locking mechanism but rather try to see how to fix the way your client is using the database, see [mysql docs for commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)

> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

in case you decide to implement locking (which again, I wouldn't recommend), one good way to do it is as follows:

```
import redis

have_lock = False
my_lock = redis.Redis().lock("my_key")
try:
    have_lock = my_lock.acquire(blocking=True)
    if have_lock:
        print("Got lock.")
    else:
        print("Did not acquire lock.")

finally:
    if have_lock:
        my_lock.release()
```

for detailed explanation see http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html

Comment: Does MySQL-python implement wait functions by default. I am sorry, but I don't understand how I can make it work without a wait function somewhere in the code.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing your queries / SQL etc. also, its better to include entire stack trace rather than just the error itself

Comment: I see, so, do you know what that `with` statement actually does? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067690/context-manager-for-pythons-mysqldb

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand the answer. It seems like I actually don't need to implement a lockfile mechanism. I just need to make sure the calls to db are being made correctly, and mysql_free_result is being called. However, I am not sure how to ensure that.

Comment: My guess is that `with` and `con.commit ()` are not going well together,  delete `con.commit ()` and see how it goes