# Does 'mysql.connector.connect()' support 'with' block?

Tags: python, mysql

According to the documentation [one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) [two](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-close.html) we should close connector each time we connect it.

```py
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
# do some stuff
cnx.close()
```

Does it support `with` interface to do something like this?:

```py
with mysql.connector.connect(**config):
    #do some stuff
```

Comment: Apparently not but you can [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074341/3324095).

Comment: Well, that would be very easy to test!

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know how to check if it closed