# Automate Opening and Closing the Database Connection

Tags: python, class, database-connection

I am writing a class for database queries with SQLite3 in my application. Most of the methods of the class are very similar to this:

```
def getPrice(self, symbol, date):
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    conn = sqlite3.connect('stocks.db')
    curs =conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('''SELECT close FROM prices WHERE symbol = ? AND date = ?;''', (symbol, date))
    close = curs.fetchall()
    curs.close()
    return close
```

The only difference is the database query and the number of arguments. Is there a possibility to abstract the opening and closing of the database connection away?

I know that it would be probably easier to use a ORM like SQLAlchemy. But I want to understand how I solve this kind of problem in general, not only in relation to databases.

Thanks for your suggestions!

EDIT: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107297/looking-for-a-more-pythonic-way-to-access-the-database) basically answers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First.  You'll be much, much happier with one -- and only one -- global connection.  Configuration changes are much easier if you do this in exactly one place.

Second, use the `with` statement and the context manager library.

```
from contextlib import closing
from my_database_module import the_global_connection

def getPrice(
    with closing(the_global_connection.cursor())
        curs.execute('''SELECT close FROM prices WHERE symbol = ? AND date = ?;''', (symbol, date))
        close = curs.fetchall()
    return close
```

Your database module looks like this:

```
import sqlite3
the_global_connection = sqlite3.connect( "stocks.db" )
```

This gives you the ability to change databases, or database server technology in exactly one place.

Comment: contextlib sounds promissing. I will look into this. A Global Connection is also an aspect which I will implement. Thanks.

Comment: I've got another question about the global DB-connection. When I build my own database-class "database" I do have to instantiate and call this class every time I want a connection:
`db = database()` and `conn=db.the_global_connection`. Is there some easier way with less code? Or maybe a good example how to work with different classes? Sorry, if that is trivial to you, but I just started with OOP.

Comment: "and call this class every time I want a connection: db = database()".  A single, global connection *object* is what I'm telling you to do.  A single, global connection object.  Only create one instance of the db connection.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of Python2.6, `sqlite.connect` [returns a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically
>   commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the
>   transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed:

Therefore, **do not decorate the connection with `contextlib.closing`** -- otherwise, you will lose the commit/rollback behavior and instead only get the `connection.close()` called upon exiting the `with-statement`.

Per [PEP249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

```
... closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause
an implicit rollback to be performed.
```

So the commit/rollback behavior is much more useful than simply calling close.

---

You could use a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers):

```
import contextlib

def query(sql,args):
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect('stocks.db')) as conn:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(sql,args))
        close = curs.fetchall()
        return close

def getPrice(self, symbol, date):
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    sql = '''SELECT close FROM prices WHERE symbol = ? AND date = ?'''
    args = (symbol, date)
    return query(sql, args)
```

Since you have many functions like `getPrice` which differ only by the SQL and arguments, you could reduce the repetitious boiler-plate code by defining the `query` function.

You could also define a context manager to rollback the connection on errors and commit as well as close upon exiting the with block. An example of this (for MySQL) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067690/context-manager-for-pythons-mysqldb), adapting it to sqlite3 should not be difficult..

Reference:

- The [contextlib.closing decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)

Comment: While that's an improvement, in particular regarding resource management, it doesn't save much code over what OP presented.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate that logic into an object, pass that object to the data access object and ask it to call the methods.

Aspects or decorators might be a good way to do things.

You don't mention pooling or transactions.  Think about those as well.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by aspects? I never heard of this concept. Thanks for the other ideas.

Comment: Aspect-oriented programming.  In Python they're called decorators: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators